# Is it possible to make an in-sample dynamic forecast / prediction for an ARIMA model?

Tags: r, arima, prediction, stata

We are trying to check to what extent the changing X-values might explain the observed trend in Y.

- By "in-sample" I mean: using the same data as was used for the model building.
- By "dynamic" I mean: not using observed Y-series but the forecasted Y-series.

Questions:

1. Our idea is that if the observed values diverge from this prediction, this suggests there *may* be some further non-measured explanatory variables (a hypothesis put forth but for which there is no good data). And if predicted ~observed, there is "no room" for this specific competing hypothesis. **Does this make sense as an information-gathering exercise (not a formal test)?**
2. Is it possible to technically achieve this with either R or Stata?  We have already fitted a seasonal ARIMA model.

   R:

   ```
   xreg <- cbind(A,B,C)
   mod  <- arima(Y, order=c(3,0,0), seasonal=list(order=c(1,1,1), period=12), 
                 xreg=xreg)
   ```

   Stata:

   ```
   arima Y A B C, arima(3,0,0) sarima(1,1,1,12)
   ```

   Now, we would like to see what that fitted model produces for the same data, without using the observed Y-values (except for the first values needed as initial values). I have found out that Stata should probably in principle do this with:

   ```
   predict Y2, dynamic (tm(2001m01))y
   ```

   However, the person using Stata tells me that this, too gives a nearly perfect fit, the same as without the dynamic, so perhaps this is not the solution.

   In R, I have not found a solution for this in `forecast()` or `predict.arima` but perhaps I missed something.

Comment: Thank you for editing to clarify your question. (Note that I have edited it further; please ensure it still says what you want it to.)  Your first question is a viable statistics question for this site.  The second question is really about the software, &/or a tutorial, neither of which is quite on topic.  Be aware that you may get an answer to #1 w/o an answer to #2.

Answer (score 0):

Given that this is almost a year old post without any answer, I will add here a pretty silly non-R answer in hope somebody else might have an R-specific answer, as I would like to see solution to this in R.

Non-R answer: Use Eviews. The whole business of dynamic/static and in-sample/out-of-sample forecasting is briantly easy in Eviews, where for every estimated object you can easily AND separately control the estimation and forecasting samples. Moreover, for all estimated objects you can also easily control whether forecasts are static of dynamic - either directly form the object if it allows forecasting, or by making a model out of the object.